# Career path to professor with an engineering background in Germany

Tags: career-path, professorship, university, engineering, germany

I am in the final year of my master in mechatronics engineering in Germany, and I want to work as a researcher or a professor in a  university since i believe a professor/researcher has more freedom than an engineer within a company.

I don't have any experiences in the academic field, so I suppose I have to get some somehow.

What are good option to pursue as a career path in Germany to get a professor position at a university? Do I need to get a PhD? Is it better to become assistant professor on that path, or a research engineer?

Thank you

Comment: In which country do you leave ? What do you want to teach ? I am not sure of your definition of freedom...

Comment: i live in germany

Comment: Why are you saying a professor/researcher has more freedom than an engineer ?

Comment: It's just that in a company there is a more strict hiearchy, you don't get to work on the projects that you want, you are more bound to satisfy the clients need, while in research you do that for you own curiosity, it's like creating the new knowledge that will later have an application in engineering, please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: you're not wrong. But thinking you would do everything you want as a researcher is false too. I agree that you're bound to satisfy the need of a client as an engineer, but you don't have to deal as much as a researcher with budget for example. Do you like to teach ? have you any experience in this domain ?

Comment: No,unfortunately I don’t have experience with teaching, but i am relatively young so i believe that I have enough time to learn

Comment: Ok so reword your question. You don't have any experience in the academics field right ? Before being a researcher, you must at least get some experience. The question here is not which path you should take. I will reword a bit, then put more infos. 2 sec ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41437/discussion-between-mehdi-and-gautier-c).

Answer (score 0):

Your chances of becoming an academic researcher without a PhD are negligible. If you want to take this path, that is the first step. However, as far as I know long-term job prospects in German engineering faculties are not better than in other parts of academia (and maybe worse). Furthermore, many departments prefer if there PhD students have experience in the industry. You can certainly apply without such an experience, but competition is strong.

My advice is: Get an entry level job in the industry. If after two or three years you would still like to do research, apply for PhD positions at universities and research institutes. When you have your PhD, you can look for research positions in the industry or decide to stay in academia and start on the long hard road to a permanent position. If you then still want to become a professor (why would you? Usually you'd be a glorified manager and hardly do any research yourself.), you can do a habilitation. If you are extremely lucky (in addition to being very good, successful and a great networker), you'd might get a position as a professor someday. Chances for that are slim.

Comment: Maybe there is more opportunities in research in the field of mechatronics ? seeing how much they are needed now ?

Comment: To be honest, from what I've heard there is not much difference between industry research and research as (let's say) a Fraunhofer Institute, but to be honest that's not my field. There are certainly opportunities, but there is still much competition and not much of the "freedom" OP is looking for. Most freedom you have with your own business.

Comment: Ok I see. So industry first then PhD. Not a bad idea ! And yeah, freedom is hard to get.

Comment: @Mehdi Please don't be so fast to accept my answer. Give it some time, there might come other great answers (from someone doing engineering research in academia). I of course appreciate if you upvote my answer and if after a day or so you still think my answer is the best one you can still accept it.

Comment: I think this answer is bad advice. I'm in engineering, and *do not know a single researcher* who came back to do a PhD after starting in industry. The more typical path involving industry seems to be Masters, PhD, career up to some research management position in industry, then get back to university as full professor. I could answer in more detail if this question is being reopened.

Comment: @silvado I know some people who were engineer and did a PhD after 5+ years in the industry :x

Comment: @GautierC and how many of those are professors now?

Comment: @silvado one for sure, I think the 2 others went back to the industry because research was boring for them ^^

Comment: @GautierC yes I guess it is possible, but to me seems very uncommon. You have to get a PhD in any case to become professor, so why not get that as quickly as possible?

Comment: @silvado In the engineering departments I know (not mechatronics), about half of the phd students came from the industry and all professors have strong ties to the industry. However, that's not the only reason why I advise OP to first get some experience in the industry. The other is that I have the impression that OP doesn't really know what working in the industry or in academia is like.

Comment: @silvado I agree. But at the same time, if you got for a PhD, you're closing yourself some industry doors. Because you cost more than the average guy, while not bringing much more. But hte problem is that op is (wrongly or not) thinking that academia is better than industry in term of freedom, I think he should experience a bit before going only to academia.